# Facebook Graph API - Issue cover_photo when creating a test page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I'm developing a Facebook App and i need to create a Test Page.
I'm following the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-pages) and i'm stuck at the step 3: Creating a test page using Graph API.
It doesnt matter what URL i set to the `cover_photo` field, i always receive:

> (#100) Params cover_photo with a valid URL is required for creating a
>   page.

I tried different size, extension. I also re-used the picture field url.

Here are the parameters of the POST request:

- category_enum:
  ADVERTISING_AGENCY
- name:
  Test-Kraken-Name
- about:
  test about
- [picture](https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536853273994-5d28a729533d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=326c66194f23f2e8b5b80ed2aad9dad7&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80)
- [cover_photo](https://scontent.fmla1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/16112950_10211378042430071_1006449081233192925_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=4758ee8d509b8a4061aae003d1e39a42&oe=5C310C52)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thank to the Facebook Developer Community.

So the cover_photo, instead of being a url, must be an object with a url field and the url as value.

As an example in the Graph API Explorer:

name: `cover_photo`

value: `{"url": "https://path.to/image.png"}`